# Is HTML Email Obfuscation safe enough to stop bots?

Tags: security, email, bots

I know that most javascript email obfuscation solutions stop bots dead in their tracks - but sometimes it's hard to use/insert javascript in places.

To that end I was wondering if anyone knew if the bots were smart enough to translate HTML entities in HEX and DEC into valid email strings?

For example, lets say I have a function that randomly converts the string characters into one of three forms - is this enough?

```
hide_email($email)
{
    $s='';
    foreach(str_split($email)as$l)
    {
        switch(rand(1,3))
        {
            case 1:$s.='&#'.ord($l).';';break;
            case 2:$s.='&#x'.dechex(ord($l)).';';break;
            case 3:$s.=$l;
        }
    }
    return$s;
}
```

which makes first.last@email.com into something like:

```
&#x66;i&#x72;&#115;&#x74;&#46;&#108;a&#115;&#116;@e&#x6d;a&#105;&#x6c;&#46;&#x63;om
```

I would assume that the bot creators would have already added a regex pattern for something like this this...

Comment: Nothing is ever **safe enough** :)

Comment: @BoltClock: no *one* thing is ever safe enough, which is why we practice defense in depth. Now excuse me while I fumble with my belt and suspenders...

Comment: @Steven Sudit: fair... enough.

Comment: Consider replacing email addresses with an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not think this particularly safe.  Were I writing code to interpret HTML, decoding entities to their corresponding characters would be among the first bits of code to go in.

As a further defense, I would suggest judicious use of tags (such as the `<span>` tag), perhaps even nested.  That takes more effort to decode and still does not require Javascript.

Comment: True, decoding entities isn't very hard.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be shocked if a bot used a client that did an HtmlDecode before returning the results.

Answer (score 2):

There was an interesting article I read awhile ago about a guy who posted a web page with nine different methods of obfuscation, and waited a year to see how much each e-mail address got.

Here's a link to the article: [Nine Ways to Obfuscate E-mail Addresses Compared](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/).  Some of the pictures in the sidebar may not be safe for work, if your work frowns on girls in bikinis.